# intent filter android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE not found

Tags: android, android-intent, filter, connectivity

in manifest in receiver tag and in its intent filter tag Android Studio does not offer action `android.net.conn`.
what should I do now?

Comment: What do you mean that it is "not found"?

Comment: I mean IDE does not offer it in code completion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what should I do now?

You should type it in yourself.

You should also note that this broadcast will not be sent to manifest-registered receivers as of Android 7.0. That may be why Android Studio no longer offers it for code-completion when editing the manifest.

Comment: @Ali Bakhtiari, please check as correct the answer you think it was helpful to solve your problems. Thank you.